# A commiteee of 6 people is to be chosen from a group of 12 (6 men, 6 women) What is the probability that a committee will have exactly 5 women in it?

Tags: probability

A commiteee of 6 people is to be chosen from a group of 12 (6 men, 6 women) What is the probability that a committee will have exactly 5 women in it?

Is it (6/12 * 5/11 * 4/10 * 3/9 * 2/8) (6/12)?

Comment: check your last factor and if it is combination or permutation...

Answer (score 2):

No, you are expected to find the total number of possible committees, which is choosing $6$ of your $12$ people.  Then you are to find the number of committees with exactly $5$ women, so you choose $5$ women and $1$ man from the two available pools.  How many committees does that give you with the proper mix?  Then divide by the total number of committees to get the probability.